# Write to a new sheet in a loop

Tags: r, loops, split, r-xlsx

My loop is completely doing what I want it to do apart from when writing out the data I want it to loop through and open a new sheet each time, it is not doing this but simply overwriting the data in the single excel file. My code is:

```
file2 <- paste("filelocation", sep = "")
write.xlsx(Combined, file2, sheetName = (i))
```

I do not know why this isn't working as this exact same code is working for me earlier in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example that writes a workbook with three identical sheets. Change the sheet contents to suit...

```
library(openxlsx)

wb = createWorkbook()
for (i in 1:3) {
  sheet_name = paste('mtcars', i)
  addWorksheet(wb, sheet_name)
  writeData(wb, sheet_name, mtcars)
}

saveWorkbook(wb, 'my_workbook.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
write.xlsx(Combined, file2, sheetName = (i), append=TRUE)
```

From `xlsx` documentation:

> **append** a logical value indicating if x should be appended to an existing file. If TRUE the file is read from disk.

## Edit:

> This does not work – Natasha Jones

This code works for me as intended:

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(mtcars, "test.xlsx", sheetName ="firstSheet")
write.xlsx(mtcars, "test.xlsx", sheetName ="secondSheet", append=TRUE)
write.xlsx(mtcars, "test.xlsx", sheetName ="thirdSheet", append=TRUE)
```

The resulting .xlsx file has 3 sheets! You have to pass a character string to the argument `sheet`

> sheetName a character string with the sheet name. I.e.

```
for (i in 1:4) {
  write.xlsx(mtcars, "test.xlsx", sheetName = as.character(i), append=TRUE)
}
```

This works for me also...